# AngularJS: data is being updated in controller but it is not shown in the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

In my AngularJS application, I have the following code:

example.html

```
<div>                           
    <p>{{name}}</p>
</div>

<div>
    <button ng-click="someFunction()"> </button>
</div>
```

exampleController.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('exampleController', ['$scope', 'myService', 
function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.someFunction = function() {

    }

    function updateName() {
        $scope.name = myService.getName();
    }

    updateName();

}]);
```

The problem is that {{name}} is only updated in the html when I click in the button. The updateName() function is running correctly and $scope.name is being correctly defined, but {{name}} is only shown when I click in some button to call some function. I don’t know why {{name}} is not shown when the page is loaded. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is your controller declared? It's not in your exampleController above

Comment: I had hidden that information. Added it now.

Comment: What calls updateName? It doesn't look to be called from anywhere in the code you posted

Comment: Added the caller function.

Comment: Also hasn't this been solved as you marked the answer below as the solution?

Comment: Yes, the provided solution by Hylianpuffball has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular lifecycle can take some getting use to, but in a nutshell, **angular directives only get re-evaluated during an angular event, like ng-click.**  This is one reason it's so important to use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`.

In this case, if your method isn't being called inside of the angular event cycle (like if it was called through jQuery, a simple `window.onload` call, or the default `window.setTimeout` method), you won't see any changes.  You'll have to use an ng- event or angular's `$timeout` service.

To get something to run when your app starts, you can use `module.run`, as seen on this page.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

```
angular.module('MyMod', []).run(
    //Your code here, like
    updateName();
)};
```

Also, try reading up more on the lifecycle here:
http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/

Comment: The OP is using ng-click

Comment: Yes, and the UI is working after calling `someFunction()` (which doesn't actually do anything).  The call to `updateName()` is probably happening outside the angular event cycle, so the changes aren't being seen until the next call to $apply (which would happen when the button is clicked an ng-click is run)